updated Ubuntu to 24.04 LTS now can't boot Windows 10 no grub
I have a dual boot Acer Aspire. Been dual booting for years. Ubuntu suggested an update to 24.04 LTS and now I cannot get to Windows. Where's Grub and the ability to edit it?

This question is similar to: Dual-boot boot menu does not show up after installing Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

replace /etc/default/grub and /etc/grub.d/* files with the same files from the Ubuntu 24.04 ISO file; mount the ISO file, open /casper directory, mount the minimal.squashfs, and copy /etc/default/grub and /etc/grub.d/* files from mounted minimal.squashfs to your Ubuntu partition, and sudo update-grub

This question is similar to: Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
